# SymmetricDS Android demos both register but do not sync

Tags: android, symmetricds

(x-post from SymmetricDS forum)

Do you have a working example of using SymmetricDS 3.8 to sync an Android application with a demo root node?  I've worked through both of JumpMind's examples, and both fail with ECONNREFUSED against localhost:31415.

It looks like even though they know how to register with the root node on a different machine, they try to sync with it on localhost instead.

Here's a walkthrough of how to build and (unsuccessfully) run both of the existing samples.

**Sample 1:**

[Jumpmind's original demo from 2012](http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/synchronizing-android-applications-part1) used the Notepad Application, and many of the steps assume you're running in Eclipse and have their Pro version.  There are a few hoops to make it compile in a modern Android Studio with the freeware version of SymmetricDS.

- in Studio, New Project -> Import from `Android/Sdk/samples/android-23/legacy/NotePad`
- do a test compile and run to make sure it works unmodified
- [download and extract sample 2](https://support.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/extras/Android-FileSync-Demo.zip) to get the libs
- extract the libs into Notepad/app/libs/
- edit your apps gradle rule, add a compile dependency, thus:

  `dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }`
- gradle sync
- paste the recommended code from the tutorial into the *second* OnCreate in NotePadProvider.java.(the first one is in a `static class DatabaseHelper`)
- modify REGISTRATION_URL to point to your root node
- modify NODE_GROUP_ID appropriately.  If you're using the demo server, this should be "store".
- I used an external ID of "android-003", because that's what's used in sample #2.
- Don't forget to open registration for your external ID.  Something like

  symadmin --properties corp-000.properties open-registration store android-003
- observe the logcat failure

  `Building transport url: http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000/push?nodeId=android-003&securityToken=88b79dcc9617099aec015ae5ed800b&hostName=localhost&ipAddress=10.0.2.15
  Could not communicate with node 'corp:000:000' at http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000 because of unexpected error
  org.jumpmind.exception.IoException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 31415) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED`

**Sample 2:**

[Jumpmind's newer sample](http://www.jumpmind.com/blog/android-file-sync-in-symmetricds-3-8) includes support for file sync, which I don't care about right now.  But it's supposed to work against the demo node corp-000 right out of the box.  At least for me, it doesn't.

Here's what you have to do:

- [download the source](https://support.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/extras/Android-FileSync-Demo.zip)
- modify REGISTRATION_URL (to use the dev machine's non-localhost IP address)
- modify the manifest as described in the tutorial
- attempting to run the app will fail with `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`, I had to change the provider defined in the manifest to `com.jumpmind.syncds3.DbProvider`, because there's already an app on the default Android image that uses provider `com.google.provider.NotePad`.
- open registration for android-003 on the server / root-node
- confirm registration by looking in the server's sym_node_security table.
- Interestingly, there is no initial_load_time in that row, and it shows no sign of syncing.
- Back in your Android app, observe the same logcat errors attempting to sync against a corp-000 node on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For anyone coming this way with a similar problem, the problem is twofold.

1. The client gets its sync url from the server.  The demo server specifies a sync-url on localhost.
2. The (bad) sync URL persists in the sym tables, apparently on both the client *and* the server.

**Solution:**

If you're running on Linux, feel free to [use my scripted demo server](https://github.com/dsjstc/syeg).  It sets sync-url to the first IP address in the list instead of localhost.

Otherwise:

1. Stop your client and server.
2. The demo root node is configured with a SYNC URL on localhost in corp-000.properties. This is the source of your problem. Change it to a meaningful IP address. Use a non-standard port too, to help illustrate the problem -- this will mean adding a --port xxxx to the command you use to run the root node.
3. Delete and recreate your root node database. I'm not sure what was stale in here, but re-running the server on a new address didn't seem to suffice. There might be another way to refresh this, but starting over is easiest.
4. Delete your android node database. I used "adb shell rm -rf /data/data/com.jumpmind.*"
5. Re-run your server and client.